# Couchbase 5.1 N1QL OR operator not using index

Tags: database, couchbase, sql++

I have a strange case where I have an index in my couchbase server which was built with the command:

```
CREATE INDEX `idx_metadata` ON `dev`(`email`,`nickname`,`channelUuid`) WHERE (`type` = "user_metadata") WITH { "defer_build":true }`
```

If I run the query:

```
SELECT channelUuid FROM `dev` WHERE type="user_metadata" AND email="foo" AND nickname="bar"
```

Then it uses the index and works as expected.

If I simply change the AND to an OR like so:

```
SELECT channelUuid FROM `dev` WHERE type="user_metadata" AND (email="foo" OR nickname="bar")
```

It then uses the primary index, not the dedicated one.

What is going on?

UPDATE:

As requested here is the explain for the AND query

```
{
  "plan": {
    "#operator": "Sequence",
    "~children": [
      {
        "#operator": "IndexScan2",
        "index": "idx_metadata",
        "index_id": "d6e2fb94ae221335",
        "index_projection": {
          "primary_key": true
        },
        "keyspace": "dev",
        "namespace": "default",
        "spans": [
          {
            "exact": true,
            "range": [
              {
                "high": "\"test1@my-email.com\"",
                "inclusion": 3,
                "low": "\"test1@my-email.com\""
              },
              {
                "high": "\"Badger\"",
                "inclusion": 3,
                "low": "\"Badger\""
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "using": "gsi"
      },
      {
        "#operator": "Fetch",
        "keyspace": "dev",
        "namespace": "default"
      },
      {
        "#operator": "Parallel",
        "~child": {
          "#operator": "Sequence",
          "~children": [
            {
              "#operator": "Filter",
              "condition": "(((`dev`.`type`) = \"user_metadata\") and (((`dev`.`email`) = \"test1@my-email.com\") and ((`dev`.`nickname`) = \"Badger\")))"
            },
            {
              "#operator": "InitialProject",
              "result_terms": [
                {
                  "expr": "self",
                  "star": true
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "#operator": "FinalProject"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "text": "SELECT * FROM `dev` WHERE type=\"user_metadata\" AND (email=\"test1@my-email.com\" AND nickname=\"Badger\");"
}
```

And for the OR query:

```
{
  "plan": {
    "#operator": "Sequence",
    "~children": [
      {
        "#operator": "PrimaryScan",
        "index": "#primary",
        "keyspace": "dev",
        "namespace": "default",
        "using": "gsi"
      },
      {
        "#operator": "Fetch",
        "keyspace": "dev",
        "namespace": "default"
      },
      {
        "#operator": "Parallel",
        "~child": {
          "#operator": "Sequence",
          "~children": [
            {
              "#operator": "Filter",
              "condition": "(((`dev`.`type`) = \"user_metadata\") and (((`dev`.`email`) = \"test1@my-email.com\") or ((`dev`.`nickname`) = \"Badger\")))"
            },
            {
              "#operator": "InitialProject",
              "result_terms": [
                {
                  "expr": "self",
                  "star": true
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "#operator": "FinalProject"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "text": "SELECT * FROM `dev` WHERE type=\"user_metadata\" AND (email=\"test1@my-email.com\" OR nickname=\"Badger\");"
}
```

Comment: Please provide explain plan output for both queries to look in more details.

Comment: Also, what is the outcome of the call if query is fired forced index usage? SELECT channelUuid FROM `dev` USE INDEX(`idx_metadata`) WHERE type="user_metadata" AND (email="foo" OR nickname="bar")

Comment: Hey @Rizwan thanks for the comments, the USE INDEX statement doesn't change anything, it is still using the primary index. The answer below cracked it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Second OR doesn't have leading index key has a predicate.

```
You can create another index and it uses both indexes
CREATE INDEX `idx_metadata2` ON `dev`(`nickname`, `email`,`channelUuid`) WHERE (`type` = "user_metadata") WITH { "defer_build":true }`
```

OR

```
SELECT channelUuid 
FROM `dev` 
WHERE type="user_metadata" AND email IS NOT NULL AND (email="foo" OR nickname="bar")
```

Explanation:

```
"k1" {"a":5}
"k2" {"b":10}
"k3" {"a":20, "b":10}
CREATE INDEX ix1 ON default(a,b);
When leading index key value is MISSING that document will not be indexed. i.e. ix1 will have only entries for "k1", "k3"

SELECT * FROM default WHERE a = 5 OR b = 10;

Above query can't use the index ix1 because due to OR clause. AND should be able to use ix1.
predicate a = 5 can use index ix1 and produce right results.
predicate b = 10  will result "k2", "k3" But index doesn't have "k2", can't use the index ix1

Bottom line to use index each OR clause predicate must have leading key as predicate.

If you create the following index.

CREATE INDEX ix2 ON default(b,a);

 a = 5 uses ix1 and b = 10 uses ix2 and does UNION.
```

Comment: Hey @vsr thanks so much, this cracked it. Could you run through a bit more what is going on under the hood? I assume that OR statements need both sides to have an index with a leading key as you said, why is this? Also why does the second statement where email IS NOT NULL fix it. I understand that it puts the email as the index key but I thought the fact that email was already first would suffice.

Comment: Out of interest I profiled your two suggestions and on a bucket with 7400,000 documents the first method took 50.37ms whereas the second method took 6s, so method 1 much more performant.

Comment: "k1" {"a":5}
"k2" {"b":10}
"k3" {"a":20, "b":10}
CREATE INDEX ix1 ON default(a,b);
When leading index key value is MISSING that document will not be indexed. i.e. ix1 will have only entries for "k1", "k3"

Comment: SELECT * FROM default WHERE a = 5 OR b = 10;

Above query can't use the index ix1 because due to OR clause. AND should be able to use ix1.
predicate a = 5 can use index ix1 and produce right results.
predicate b = 10  will result "k2", "k3" But index doesn't have "k2", can't use the index ix1

Comment: Bottom line to use index each OR clause predicate must have leading key as predicate.

If you create the following index. a =5 uses ix1 and b = 10 uses ix2 and does UNION.

CREATE INDEX ix2 ON default(b,a);

Comment: @RobSanders When you said about the performant from method 1 is having a similar index? or Having is Not Null in the predicate with original index which you have. and Method 2 correspond to creating index with order of keys changed? I am curios here

Comment: @Rizwan I'm sure vsr could give you a better answer but as I understand it the first pass through the index will not filter out any rows as email IS NOT NULL always evaluates to true whereas the second query using two indexes can do a union of the two results and filter on the first pass through each index.

Comment: Method 1 uses both indexes and predicates pushed to indexer. indexer will able to position start and stop keys and produce only required results. Method 2 needs only one index but it needs scan all  values of email and then look for nickname, It doing lot of work.

Comment: Check this out better understand the N1QL https://blog.couchbase.com/a-guide-to-n1ql-features-in-couchbase-5-5-special-edition/    , https://blog.couchbase.com/author/keshav-murthy/